# Plot y axis shows strange values

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Would anyone tell me why the y axix didn't show 0 and 8? I appreciate your help!
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pylot
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data.dropna()
data = data.dropna()
data  =  data.reset_index(drop=True)
style.use("ggplot")
p = "gene_A"
pylot.scatter(data[p], data["phenotype"])
pylot.xlabel(p)
pylot.ylabel("phenotype")
pylot.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine for me. The most likely error is if you have formatting issues for datatype. Try running

```
data['phenotype'] = data['phenotype'].astype(float)
```

[image]

Comment: I just cut the data to illustrate the problem. When I read the file with other columns, only the phenotype column shows weird numbers. I am sorry. I don't have permission to share the data because I am not the owner.

Comment: then it's definitely because of datatypes. Try running astype(float) on phenotype column

Comment: I got the same y-axis. This doesn't happen to the cut file which has only 3 columns.

Comment: The number of columns is irrelevant since it's a scatter plot that only takes in the data from two columns. so then the cut version chart is plotting like it's supposed to? does the cut version have the same number of rows?

Comment: The cut version plot is correct and it has only 5 rows. The data has more than 1000 rows.

Comment: if you run data.dtypes, what is the type for phenotype column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240247/discussion-between-chris-and-user4718221).

Comment: It is int64.
I can't reply your comment on the post. Stackoverflow moves my reply to the chat.

Comment: I got the reason. When I filt out NA, the remaining rows have only 0 value in phenotype column.

Comment: Great, can you accept my answer now?

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your help!